# if-else with environmental variables

Tags: python, if-statement

I would like to have an if-else structure that checks if an environmental variable exists, as:

```
if "ENV_VAR" in os.environ:
    if os.environ["ENV_VAR"] == "one":
        do_something()
    else:
        do_something_else()
else:
    do_something_else()
```

Is there a better way to write the code, specifically to avoid writing twice the call to "do_something_else()" ?

Comment: Remember `dict.get(key, default=None)`;  it comes in handy for this kind of thing.

Comment: According to [`os.environ` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ), your code is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use os.environ.get if ENV_VAR doesn't exist it will default to None and not pass the if condition.

```py
if os.environ.get("ENV_VAR") == "one":
    do_something()
else:
    do_something_else()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do this, using [`os.getenv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv):

```
if os.getenv("ENV_VAR") == "one":
    do_something()
else:
    do_something_else()
```

Answer (score 1):

With dictionaries you can also use `.get` to provide a default value if the key is not present. In this case you could return an empty string to compare, or the actual value if successfully retrieved.

```
if os.environ.get('ENV_VAR', '') == 'one':
    do_something()
else:
    do_something_else()
```

Comment: you don't need the empty string in os.environ.get, it defaults to None and will work the same.